# ¿Cómo puedo validar si un campo de tipo fecha tiene un valor o es nulo?

Tags: c#, datetime

Estoy trayendo varios registros de una base de datos a un `datatable` y tengo 4 campos que son de tipo fecha. Al menos uno de ellos podría traer un valor `NULL` y a la hora de enlazar el campo con un control `datetimepicker` me da un error al no encontrar un valor valido.

¿Cómo podría validar el campo previamente antes de asignárselo al control?
He probado comparando el `value` del campo con `NULL` pero no me ha dado resultado.

```
if (campoFecha != null)
```

El campoFecha ya tiene el valor traído por el `datatable` y ha sido declarado como `datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar el `DbNull.Value` para validar si es null desde la db

```
if (row["nombrecampo"] != DBNull.Value){
   DateTimePicker1.Value = Conver.ToDateTime(row["nombrecampo"]);
}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya lo probe y funciona perfectamente.